# Dataframe de la variación porcentual anual en R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-dplyr, timeseries

Tengo un dataframe de **series de tiempo** en R, llamémoslo `df`, que se ve así:

```
|Date        |City_1   |City_2   |City_3   |.....|City_n   |
------------------------------------------------------------
|1980-01-01  |1        |4        |6        | ... |2        |
|1980-01-02  |2        |7        |6        | ... |5        |
|1980-01-03  |3        |7        |1        | ... |1        |
|1980-01-04  |8        |1        |8        | ... |1        |
|1980-01-05  |4        |3        |5        | ... |0        |
|  ...       |...      |...      |...      | ... |7        |
|2020-08-20  |3        |1        |8        | ... |2        |
|1980-08-21  |7        |8        |3        | ... |2        |
|1980-08-22  |8        |6        |5        | ... |0        |
|1980-08-23  |9        |8        |2        | ... |1        |
```

Aquí les presento una parte reproducible de mis datos:

```
df <- structure(c(17.86, 18.65, 18.42, 19.21, 21.34, 11.35, 10.01, 
9.67, 10.12, 10.81, 20.77, 20.99, 20.88, 20.91, 20.5, 13.8, 13.63, 
13.6, 13.02, 13.87, 22.07, 22.78, 23.24, 23.33, 24.06), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(315532800, 
315619200, 315705600, 315792000, 315878400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), 
.Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Sao Paulo", "Mexico City", "Lima", "Bogota", 
"Rio de Janeiro")))
```

Y quiero crear un nuevo dataframe que, en cada columna de ciudad, para cada fecha, tenga el porcentaje de cambio con respecto a la misma fecha del año anterior, dado por la siguiente fórmula:

```
cambio = [x(t) -x(t-1)]/x(t)
```

Para obtener un dataframe final, `df2` que debe verse así:

```
|Date        |City_1   |City_2   |City_3   |.....|City_n   |
------------------------------------------------------------
|1981-01-01  |a        |j        |s        | ... |b        |
|1981-01-02  |b        |k        |t        | ... |c        |
|1981-01-03  |c        |l        |u        | ... |d        |
|1981-01-04  |d        |m        |v        | ... |t        |
|1981-01-05  |e        |n        |w        | ... |e        |
|  ...       |...      |...      |...      | ... |f        |
|2020-08-20  |f        |o        |x        | ... |h        |
|1980-08-21  |g        |p        |y        | ... |s        |
|1980-08-22  |h        |q        |z        | ... |y        |
|1980-08-23  |i        |r        |a        | ... |u        |
```

Donde todas las letras son el porcentaje de cambio de cada día, respecto al año pasado..

Apenas estoy empezando con R, pero creo que necesitaria una función. Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Hola Valeria! Sería muy valioso si puedes compartir parte de tus datos para que quien desea ayudarte tenga un ejemplo que pueda ser reproducido. Para eso puedes usar la función `dput()` sobre tus datos, o parte de ellos, por ejemplo: `dput(head(datos))`. También puedes usar los datos disponibles en R para tu ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias, creo que pude hacer lo que me dijiste. Ojalá puedas ayudarme!

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla y clara es mediante un `left_join` a los mismos datos, combinando horizontalmente una fila, con otra exactamente un año atrás, al tener los datos actuales y el de un año es trivial hacer el calculo:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c('2021-01-18', '2022-01-18')),
                 `Sao Paulo` = c(11.34, 15.65),
                 `Mexico City` = c(20.99, 23.33),
                 check.names = FALSE
)


library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date_Prev = Date - years(1)) %>% 
  left_join(df, 
            by=c("Date_Prev" = "Date"),
            suffix  = c("", "_ant")) %>% 
  mutate(`Sao Paulo (P)` = (`Sao Paulo` - `Sao Paulo_ant`) / `Sao Paulo`,
         `Mexico City (P)` = (`Mexico City` - `Mexico City_ant`) / `Mexico City`) %>% 
  select(!contains('_ant') & !contains('_Prev'))

        Date Sao Paulo Mexico City Sao Paulo (P) Mexico City (P)
1 2021-01-18     11.34       20.99            NA              NA
2 2022-01-18     15.65       23.33     0.2753994          0.1003
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tengo un problema ejecutando este código porque mi dataframe original es de clase c('xts', 'zoo') y me resulta este error cuando corro tu código con mi dataframe: Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')". Puedes ayudarme?

Comment: Entonces lo que tienes no es un `data.frame` sino una serie de tiempo que algo totalmente distinto y de hecho merecería otra pregunta, pero rápidamente te puedo decir que intentes algo así `datos <-  as.data.frame.ts(df);datos$Date<-as.Date(as.numeric(time(df)), origin='1981-01-01')`, es importante indicar la corecta fecha de inicio de la serie de tiempo.